# Error encountered when attempting to send request to DON gateway URL

Tags: chainlink

I am using Chainlink function and I encountered error when sending request to DON gateway:
"https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/" and "https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/"

It mentioned that: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"89015367","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"sender has insufficient balance:  juels"}}

I am running the Chainlink Function to Polygon Mumbai Network, I also tried with Sepolia network and it throws me similar error. My subscription id has 3 links on it, I also funded 3 links for my contract address and more than 5 links on my EOA.

I tried to use other network, and created new subscription but nothing worked.

Comment: This issue has been fixed, both DON Hosted and User Hosted method for secret message are working now flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding more subscription links to resolve the issue.